# How to change api level 29 to 30 in expo react native App

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo

**This Message was appear when i upload my app bundle to play store**

Your app currently targets API level 29 and must target at least API level 30 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 30.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a managed workflow expo app.
To make expo target new Api level 30, you need to upgrade your app to Expo SDK 41 or higher.
Do the following ;

1. Upgrade your expo cli to 41 or higher -  npm i -g expo-cli expo-cli@4.4.1
2. Run expo upgrade on your project
3. Create a new build of your app for Google Paystore - expo build:android

This will now target api 30

Comment: Run on the terminal of the project:  expo upgrade

Answer (score 2):

**Open `build.gradle` under `android/app/`**

find the `android { }` block

Change the following version to the below:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
```

In case your current `android/app/build.gradle` has lines which look like :

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

You will have to edit the `android/build.gradle` to include :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **NON-EXPO** projects edit the `andoid/build.gradle` file as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```